# How to access key value in array of objects - java

Tags: java

I'm getting result from cloudant db and response type would be Document object.

This is my query:

```java
FindResult queryResult = cloudantConfig.clientBuilder()
    .postFind(findOptions)
    .execute()
    .getResult();
```

This is my result from cloudant db:

```json
    {
      "bookmark": "Tq2MT8lPzkzJBYqLOZaWZOQXZVYllmTm58UHpSamxLukloFUc8BU41GXBQAtfh51",
      "docs": [
        {
          "sports": [
            {
              "name": "CRICKET",
              "player_access": [
                "All"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I'd like to access 'name' and 'player access,' but I can only go up to'sports,' and I can't get to 'name' or 'player access.' This is how I attempted to obtain 'name.'

```java
queryResult.getDocs().get(0).get("sports").get(0).get("name");
```

With above one I'm getting an error like this `The method get(int) is undefined for the type Object`

I'm receiving the values when I try to get up to'sports.'

This is how I obtain sports:

```java
queryResult.getDocs().get(0).get("sports");
```

When I sysout the aforementioned sports, I get the results below.

```java
[{name=CRICKET, player_access=[All]}]
```

So, how do I gain access to 'name' and 'player access' here? Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Please show a complete runnable example in your question.

Comment: There's an extra ")" in `queryResult.getDocs().get(0).get("sports")).get(0).get("name");`, after "sports"

Comment: @JimmyFlash Yeah it was typo, in code there is no extra right parenthesis

Comment: Would you mind posting the Document class or the class the `sports` collection is deserialized to.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealed with JSON values recently. But ended up just using regex and splitting/matching from there.

You can regex everything from the "name" (not including until the last comma) and do the same for sport Access.

Be aware that this is just a work around, and not the best option. But sometimes JSON objects on Java can be Tricky.